# From SQLServer syntax to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I've been playing around with this query for some time now but I can't seem to make it work in an Oracle DB. I use SQLServer syntax that works with SQLServer 2008 at least (don't know about earlier versions).

```
INSERT INTO WELCOME_PAGE_ITEMS
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 FROM WELCOME_PAGE_ITEMS),
     'panel-' + (SELECT CAST(COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(20))
                   FROM WELCOME_PAGE_ITEMS),
     1,
     (SELECT COUNT(PREFERED_ORDER) + 1
        FROM WELCOME_PAGE_ITEMS
       WHERE PREFERED_POSITION = 1),
     0,
     0,
     'Custom Portlet',
     1,
     1,
     3,
     0
```

It gives me problems with the COALESCE function as well as with the string concatenation of `'panel'+X`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: In Oracle you're doing string concatenation with `||`

Answer (score 0):

You've got several small problems in your query:

- the string concatenation operator in Oracle is `||` (as mentioned by @yamny)
- (assuming ID is numeric) use `to_char()` to convert a number to a string instead of `CAST`

Small example that should get you going (`DUAL` is just a dummy table I use for data generation - Oracle always requires a table to `SELECT` from):

```
with welcome_page_items(id) as (
  select cast(null as number) from dual
)
SELECT 'panel-' || to_char(coalesce(max(id), 0) + 1)
FROM welcome_page_items
```